# Populating a sparse list with random 1's

Tags: python

I need to populate a list with a few 1's in random places. I can successfully create a list of random numbers with:

```
from random import randint
l = [randint(0,1023) for _ in range(0,10)]
```

How do I populate a list with 1's in the position specified by l?

Comment: What are you using to implement the sparse list in the first place? There is no default sparse list type in Python.

Comment: How do you plan to use the information? Depending on your problem, you might be better off working with `l` (or `set(l)`) directly.

Comment: I need to create a large list of 0's with 10 - 40 l's in random places to benchmark an algorithm

Comment: You cannot guarantee generating 10 - 40 random places using this approach. See "Flaw in both of the above approaches" in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17523441/78845).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## A Sparse List

My understanding of "sparse list" is that most (say, more than 95% of) values will be zero and for reasons of **memory efficiency** you don't wish to *store* these (*cf.* [Sparse array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array)).

### List comprehension

Using your list comprehension, you can use [***Conditional Expression Resolution***](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html) (*foo* `if` *condition* `else` *bar*) to determine whether a one or a zero is at that position. For example:

```
In [1]: from random import randint

In [2]: l = [randint(0,1023) for _ in range(0,10)]

In [3]: l
Out[3]: [987, 356, 995, 192, 21, 22, 1013, 375, 796, 339]

In [4]: 1 if 987 in l else 0
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: 1 if 988 in l else 0
Out[5]: 0
```

This means that you don't need to populate the second list you mention in your question, you could just iterate over the range 0 - 1023 and use:

```
1 if index in l else 0
```

### Dictionary comprehension

Alternatively, you could use a [***dictionary comprehension***](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). I think this is more readable:

```
In [1]: from random import randint
In [2]: l = {randint(0, 1023): 1 for _ in xrange(0, 10)}
```

This will generate a dictionary like this:

```
In [3]: l
Out[3]: 
{216: 1,
 381: 1,
 384: 1,
 392: 1,
 396: 1,
 472: 1,
 585: 1,
 630: 1,
 784: 1,
 816: 1}
```

Then you access the elements, specifying a default value of zero. If the value at the requested position is set, you'll get your one:

```
In [4]: l.get(216, 0)
Out[4]: 1
```

If the value is not set, you'll get a zero:

```
In [5]: l.get(217, 0)
Out[5]: 0
```

To obtain a list of the positions:

```
In [6]: l.keys()
Out[6]: [384, 392, 472, 630, 216, 585, 396, 381, 784, 816]
```

### Flaw in both of the above approaches

`randint(0, 1023)` could emit the same number more than once, leading to *clashes*, which would result in fewer than the required number of ones.

### Tying it all together

I would wrap the dictionary-based implementation in a `class` to make it easy to (re-)use.

```
from random import randint


class RandomSparseList(object):
    def __init__(self, size, min_bits, max_bits):
        self.size = int(size)
        self.bits = {}
        self.bits_set = randint(min_bits, max_bits)
        while self.bits_set > len(self.bits):
            self.bits[randint(0, self.size)] = 1 

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index < 0 or index >= self.size:
            raise IndexError
        return self.bits.get(int(index), 0)

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in xrange(self.size):
            yield self.__getitem__(i)

    def __contains__(self, index):
        return index in self.bits

    def __repr__(self):
        return '[{}]'.format(', '.join(str(x) for x in self))

    def set_bits(self):
        return self.bits.keys()
```

### Example usage

#### I've put this `class` in a file:

```
In [1]: from random_sparse_list import RandomSparseList
```

#### Create an instance:

```
In [2]: rsl = RandomSparseList(1024, 10, 40)
```

#### Check the length of the list:

```
In [3]: len(rsl)
Out[3]: 1024
```

#### Which bits are set?

```
In [4]: rsl.set_bits()
Out[4]: 
[523,
 400,
 285,
 158,
 419,
 434,
 701,
 67,
 843,
 846,
 591,
 720,
 470,
 864,
 912,
 739,
 996,
 485,
 489,
 234,
 1005,
 573,
 381,
 784]
```

24: That's certainly in the range of 10-40.

#### Random-access:

```
In [5]: rsl[523]
Out[5]: 1

In [6]: rsl[524]
Out[6]: 0
```

#### Is a bit set?

```
In [7]: 400 in rsl
Out[7]: True

In [8]: 401 in rsl
Out[8]: False
```

#### Iteration over the list:

```
In [9]: for index, value in enumerate(rsl):
   ...:     if value:
   ...:         print '{} found at index {}'.format(value, index)
   ...:         
1 found at index 67
1 found at index 158
1 found at index 234
1 found at index 285
1 found at index 381
1 found at index 400
1 found at index 419
1 found at index 434
1 found at index 470
1 found at index 485
1 found at index 489
1 found at index 523
1 found at index 573
1 found at index 591
1 found at index 701
1 found at index 720
1 found at index 739
1 found at index 784
1 found at index 843
1 found at index 846
1 found at index 864
1 found at index 912
1 found at index 996
1 found at index 1005
```

#### String representation:

```
In [10]: rsl
Out[10]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

### Note

A [***`set`***](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)-based implementation would be even more memory efficient but the [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) above can be easily changed to contain (random or otherwise) values other than `0` and `1`.

## Update

Inspired by this question and the lack of a standard sparse `list` implementation, I've added a  [sparse_list](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sparse_list/0.1) implementation to the Cheese Shop. You can install it with `pip install sparse_list` and then the `RandomSparseList` implementation is much simpler for you:

```
from sparse_list import SparseList
from random import randint


class RandomSparseList(SparseList):
    def __init__(self, size, min_bits, max_bits):
        super(RandomSparseList, self).__init__(size, 0)
        self.bits = randint(min_bits, max_bits)
        while self.bits > len(self.elements):
            self.elements[randint(0, self.size)] = 1
```

This will work exactly as in the examples above but with a few extras such as extended slicing. You can read (and contribute to) the source [on GitHub](https://github.com/johnsyweb/python_sparse_list).

Comment: I don't think I worded my question quite right: I want to populate the positions of another list with 1's - but those positions are generated by my 'l' above. I need to keep track of the positions to benchmark an algorithm. I can't see how your solution does this I'm sorry.

Answer (score 8):

> I need to create a large list of 0's with 10 - 40 l's in random places
>   to benchmark an algorithm.

Might this work for you?

```
import random

zeros = [0] * 1024
ones = [1] * random.randint(10, 40)
l =  zeros + ones
random.shuffle(l)

# the list l contains many zeros and 10 - 40 1's in random places.

where_the_ones_are = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x == 1]
```

Comment: No, I need to know the positions of the 1's: the point of the algorithm is to find them - that's why I generated a list of random positions initially. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I edited my answer adding how to obtain the list of indexes, please have a look.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it's not *sparse*.

Comment: @Johnsyweb I'm rusty on algebra and definitions. By "sparse" I mean the most of items are 0. Here we have a large list of zeros with 10 to 40 ones. Can't it be considered sparse?

Comment: For my purposes (mathematical), as long as <10% of the list is a 1, the list is sparse.

Comment: Apologies. What I should have said is that this is a "naive implementation" of a "sparse" list. The memory required to store 1,024 zeros is not great, but if you wanted a list of 10^100 elements with only 10-40 ones among them, then this would be a huge waste. This is what [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17523441/78845) addresses.

Comment: I see. Well, I'm not implementing a list that big at the moment so I'm not worrying about it!

Comment: Johnsyweb's answer deserves much more attention than mine, @TomKealy glad you changed your mind and accepted his answer, I learnt a lot too :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet:

```
ones_lst = [SOME_VALUE] * 1024
for val in l:
  ones_lst[val] = 1
```

Here replace `SOME_VALUE` to the different value you use except one (maybe zero)

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. The postions and the number of 1s are both random. You'll have the positions in ones array to check if your algorithm works.

```
from random import randint

MAX_NUMS=1000
#big array of 0s
arr = [0] * MAX_NUMS

#How many 1s do you want?
numOnes=randint(10, 40)
ones=[1]*numOnes

#Fill array with random postions 
for i in range(0,numOnes-1):
        ones[i] =  randint(0,MAX_NUMS-1)
print ones

#Set arr to 1 for each random postion
for pos in ones:
        arr[pos]=1
print arr
```

Answer (score 1):

python list with random write access, like Array in javascript

```py
class RandomWriteList(list):
    "list with random write access, like Array in javascript"
    def __setitem__(self, idx, val):
        try:
            super().__setitem__(idx, val)
        except IndexError:
            self += [None] * (idx - len(self))
            self.append(val)

L = RandomWriteList()
L[2] = "2"
L[5] = "5"
assert L == [None, None, '2', None, None, '5']
```

---

im using `list` as base class, because [collections.UserList](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList) is not JSON serializable
see also [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable/31207881#31207881)

```py
# no: TypeError: Object of type RandomWriteList is not JSON serializable
import collections
class RandomWriteList(collections.UserList):
    # ...
```